# In WinJS, How Do I Call openPane()?

Tags: javascript, uisplitviewcontroller, winjs, win-universal-app

**What I want:**

A button on a closed `splitView` that calls `.openPane()`.

**What I've tried:**

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn919970.aspx) MSDN documentation says that `SplitView` should have a method called `showPane()`.  Looking at [this](http://codepen.io/codemonkeychris/pen/XJBbOP) codepen example makes it seem like I can just `WinJS.Namespace.define()` a random var, put a `splitView: null` on it and have it all work but it complains that `openPane()` is not a supported method or property.  Looking at the code Visual Studio 2015 generates, I would expect to call `window.mySpitView.splitView.openPane()` which complains about `splitView` being null (because it's set to `null` at the top). I also tried doing `WinJS.UI.SplitView.openPane()` which also complains that `.openPane()` is not a supported property or method.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and WinJS 4.X (I installed fresh from NuGet so it had better be the most recent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instance of the SplitView has the `openPane`. You're calling it as a static method which just isn't there.
Find your SplitView with some selector like the following

```
var splitView = document.querySelector('[data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SplitView"]');
splitView.winControl.openPane();
```

That should do the trick

Comment: So I'm doing this in a Universal App, is there a "best practice" place to put the reference to the actual splitview?

Comment: I really don't know if there is, but I'm also not sure that would be a good idea. Every "official" code from documentation or apps from Microsoft uses that pattern to retrieve the control you need.

Comment: As in, every time they need to interact with the splitview they use a `document.querySelector()`?

Comment: if you know you'll use it pretty often I guess you could cache it somewhere.